# MAX amd MIN events by hour between two dates

Tags: sql, group-by, max, presto, min

I have a transactional table with the transaction's timestamp and other columns, like this.

```
transaction_timestamp | column_1  | column_2....
--------------------------------------------------
2023-01-01 15:03:00   | some_data | some_data ...
2023-01-02 17:03:00   | some_data | some_data ...
```

With this table, I want to create a report that gives me the `MAX` and `MIN` number of events by HOUR between two dates. Something like this:

```
hour  | min | max 
----------------
14:00 | 200 | 550
15:00 | 300 | 700
16:00 | 150 | 300
```

and so on for every hour in 24 hours of the day.

I'm able to count the number of events by hour in one day:

```
SELECT HOUR(transaction_timestamp),
COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY HOUR(transaction_timestamp)
ORDER BY HOUR(transaction_timestamp)
```

Obtaining something like this:

```
hour  | count
-------------
14:00 | 100 
15:00 | 304 
16:00 | 105
```

And I know this data structure could be the input to obtain the MAX and MIN values for several days. But I don't know how to get slice this query for each day in between the dates I want to create the report in one single query

I'm working with PrestoSQL, but whether the answers are supported on other engines doesn't matter.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You want min and max of which column?

Comment: You expect 24 rows in total? Or is it per hour and per day?

Answer (score 0):

To get counts for each day and hour in between two dates just include the `date_trunc()` function into your existing query e.g:

```
SELECT
      date_trunc('day', transaction_timestamp) as day
    , HOUR(transaction_timestamp) as hr
    , COUNT(*) as num_trans
FROM my_table
WHERE transaction_timestamp >= from_dt
  AND transaction_timestamp < to_dt
GROUP BY
      date_trunc('day', transaction_timestamp)
    , HOUR(transaction_timestamp)
ORDER BY
      date_trunc('day', transaction_timestamp)
    , HOUR(transaction_timestamp)
```

see: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

**NB** I have NOT used `between` as the date range filter. This is due to the fact that `between` includes both the start point and finish point in the results and this can lead to error. To avoid this potential error, use the combination of `>=` with `<` for date range filtering you see above **but** the **to date** should be the date AFTER the data you want in your report. e.g:

To get all of January (and none of February):

- from_dt = 2023-01-01
- to_dt = 2023-02-01

```
    WHERE transaction_timestamp >= date('2023-01-01')
      AND transaction_timestamp < date('2023-02-01')
```